# Looping through points in an image to find date range with highest cumulative rainfall

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, loop, iteration, precipitation

New to GEE and confused about difficulty of iterating through items. I want to find the planting season, which is very location specific, and I define it as the 90 day period at a given location with the highest cumulative rainfall for a given year. The following function works for one point in one year, but I can't get it to run over all the points in an image, like the one I've provided with cropland. I think I need to rethink the approach and use a function that takes an image as an input instead of thinking I can loop through points.

```
function defineGrowingSeason (lat, lon) {  
  var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");

  var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([lat, lon]); //set region of interest

  var tzaBoundary = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Tanzania'));
  
  var precipitation = chirps.select('precipitation')
      .filterDate(ee.Date('2001-01-01'), ee.Date('2010-12-31'))
      .filterBounds(tzaBoundary)
      .map(function(image){
      return image.clip(tzaBoundary);
  });
  
  // Make a list of all possible 90 day date ranges in a year, note that this does (and should) continue into the next calendar year if the startDate begins less than 90 days before dec 31

  var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, 365, 1)
                .map(function(start) {
                  var startDate = ee.Date('2000-01-01').advance(start, 'day');
                  var endDate = ee.Date('2000-01-01').advance(ee.Number(start).add(90), 'day');
                  var startString = startDate.format('MM d');
                  var endString = endDate.format('MM d');
                  var filtered = chirps.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
                  var total = filtered.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
  
                  var stats = total.reduceRegion({
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                      geometry: roi,
                      scale: 5000,
                  });
                  return (startString).cat(' - ').cat(endString).cat(': ').cat(stats.get('precipitation_sum'));
  
                });
  // print(dates)
```

From here I make a dictionary with the date range as key and cumulative precip as value and then find the date range with the highest precip. The problem is that I cant run this function over all points in an image or feature collection, can only do one point (or polygon) at a time.

Full code here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/26f6852905b1e078fd4af5a20dfd623b